# Apply fade to margin area of html component

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is a sample code for the html and css:

**HTML**

```
<nav>...</nav>
<div class="row"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

I want a gradual fading effect in the bottom margin of the navbar.

Please help. What css property needs to be set to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your nav background is a solid color (or the "faded" part is one color), you could add an `::after` pseudo-element with a background gradient to simulate the color fading out.

[Here is a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qnmwg296/1/) of how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a fading effect on CSS, you can play with `opacity` property going from 0 to 1. Then, you have to couple this property with another property called `transition`. To create a transition effect, you must specify two things:

- the CSS property you want to add an effect to. In your case, it's `opacity`.
- the duration of the effect

So, you can try a CSS like this to change the opacity for your nav :

```
.nav
{
  opacity : 1;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition : opacity 2s;
}
```

If you know about JQuery, there are special functions to do a [fading in/out effect](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp).

Hope it will help you.